# How to prove that determinant of a linear map measures the change of volume and orientation of any measurable set.

Tags: linear-transformations, determinant

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear map represented by matrix A.

In this case the determinant of A  can be interpreted as a measure of change in orientation and volume of a measurable set in n-dimensional space.

I understand how this is derived when looking at how the volume of a n-dimensional cube is transformed under the linear map, however, I am interesed in the generalization of this property to all measurable sets in n-dimensional space.

Simply put, I am looking for some kind of verification, that the determinant represents this measure of change for any shape or more generally a measurable set. Its easy for me to see, when the shape is a square or cube with vectors as its sides, however, in a more complicated case, its not very clear to me.

Comment: See section $2.8$ of [this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch2.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.